# Ubuntu Touch - how to revert to Android

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to revert back to Android after having installed Ubuntu Touch Preview.

I have followed [the steps on the installation instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Restoring_Android). However when I try to run `sudo flash-all.sh` nothing happens. Any help?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a link to the specific page on the Ubuntu Wiki that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I first did `fastboot devices` to see if my Galaxy Nexus showed up. Then did `su` to make sure I had permission. Then `./flash-all.sh`.